# How can I deserialize and display these instances

Tags: c#, loops, serialization, output, deserialization

I created these instances for coffee types and in final I want to deserialize them and display them per instance. I created a foreach loop but it gives me a lot of repeated data and If possible I want to display data instance per instance.

Is there something else that I can use to display them?

```
public void CoffeeTypes()
    {
        Coffee coffeeType1 = new Coffee()
        {
           CoffeeID = "321",
           CoffeePrice = 1.50,
           TSpoonsSugar = 'N',
           CoffeeAmountRatio = 1,
           MilkAmountRatio = 0,
           Size = 'S'
        };

        Coffee coffeeType2 = new Coffee()
        {
            CoffeeID = "322",
            CoffeePrice = 2.99,
            TSpoonsSugar = 'N',
            CoffeeAmountRatio = 1,
            MilkAmountRatio = 0,
            Size = 'M'
        };

        Coffee coffeeType3 = new Coffee()
        {
            CoffeeID = "323",
            CoffeePrice = 4.50,
            TSpoonsSugar = 'N',
            CoffeeAmountRatio = 1,
            MilkAmountRatio = 0,
            Size = 'L'
        };

        Coffee coffeeType4 = new Coffee()
        {
            CoffeeID = "413",
            CoffeePrice = 1.99,
            TSpoonsSugar = 'Y',
            CoffeeAmountRatio = 1,
            MilkAmountRatio = 0,
            Size = 'S'
        };

        List<Coffee> coffeeData = new List<Coffee>()
        {
            coffeeType1,
            coffeeType2,
            coffeeType3,
            coffeeType4                                                     
        };

        Coffee.SerializeData(coffeeData, filePath);

        List<Coffee> coffeePosibilities = Coffee.DeserializeData<Coffee>(filePath);

        Coffee.coffeeInstance = coffeePosibilities;

        foreach (var coffee in coffeePosibilities)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Coffee Type 1 :  Coffee ID: " + coffee.CoffeeID);
            Console.WriteLine("Coffee Type 2 :  Coffee ID: " + coffee.CoffeeID);
            Console.WriteLine("Coffee Type 3 :  Coffee ID: " + coffee.CoffeeID);
            Console.WriteLine("Coffee Type 4 :  Coffee ID: " + coffee.CoffeeID);

  }
```

Comment: Not sure what is happening in `SerializeData` and `DeserializeData` method. So can not suggest anything

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I think it's just for testing that serializing works as expected and is not losing data when deserializing

Comment: `SerializeData` is working perfectly but I don't know how can I display each instance with their properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your foreach loop to output information for your current element only

```
foreach (var coffee in coffeePosibilities)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Coffee Type :  Coffee ID: {coffee.CoffeeID}");
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Ehssan that is the output that I wanted :)